# Can I send data from my website to the firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I send data from my website to the firebase?
I am interested in sending data from my website to the firebase then retrieve the data in my android app.

Comment: I don't know how your website works or tech stack used for the same. Have you looked at Firebase setup for Web / Server ?

Comment: The website is not built yet. The website will be basically a contact form with a lot of inputs (around 40).

Comment: Is a way to connect a PHP form to the firebase?

Comment: yes you can use the Javascript API or via the REST API, [read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

Comment: That is definitely possible. Find the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) or the [codelab here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can send and you do not need php at all. Just setup firebase for web correctly and you are done.

For getting started with firebase and web, checkout this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start